# Проблема вывода addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

Проблема в выводе всего что идет после for.

```
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".number"),
    clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
    textview = document.getElementById("textview"),
    result = document.getElementById("result"),
    del = document.getElementById("delete");

for( let b in button ){
button[b].addEventListener("click", function(){
    return textview.value += button[b].value;
});}    // output data

clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
     return textview.value = " ";
});     //clear

result.addEventListener("click", function(){
     return textview.value = eval(textview.value);
});     //result

del.addEventListener("click", function(){
    return textview.value = (textview.value).slice(0, -1);
});
```

Comment: "Проблема в выводе всего" - ??

Comment: Проблема в выводе всего что идет после for

Comment: Я поставлю минус сейчас Вам (. В чем, собственно, заключается "проблема", я должен угадать?

Comment: Сейчас Вы сможете "принять" ответ, щелкнув по знаку "галочка" слева от него.

Comment: @Igor спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов! (Минусы - не мои.)

Comment: @Igor я все равно не особо пока разбираюсь в этих "минусах" и тд. первый день только, нужно будет обьязательно почитать правила, чтобы более конкретно задавать вопросы. Успехов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив, а массиво-подобный объект.

Неправильно:

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
for( let b in button ){
  console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
```

Правильно:

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
for(let b = 0; b < button.length; b++){
  console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
```

или

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".number").forEach((el, b) => console.log(b));
```

```html
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
```